# Optimize checking if dictionary value exists for path

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, optimization

This question has been asked elsewhere but without a list in the middle of the dictionary path. Below I have a working solution of what I have been using to get the value and catch it if it doesn't exist. The problem is I do this several times and would like to make it a function to remove repeated code. Put a function I was trying to get working but couldn't get it to handle the lists in the middle of the path.

```
try:
   recommendation["serviceRecommendationOptions"][0]["containerRecommendations"][0]["cpu"]
except (KeyError, IndexError):
   cpu_size = "N/A"
else:
   cpu_size = str(
                recommendation["serviceRecommendationOptions"][0][
                    "containerRecommendations"
                ][0]["cpu"]
            )
```

Function I attempted but failed at:

```
def check_dict_path(d, *indices):
    sentinel = object()
    for index in indices:
        d = d.get(index, sentinel)
        if d is sentinel:
            return False
    return True


test_dict = {1: {'blah': [{'blob': 4}]}}

print check_dict_path(test_dict, 1, 'blah', 0, 'blob') # Fails
print check_dict_path(test_dict, 1, 'blah', 0, 'rob') # Fails
```

Comment: Frame challenge. It sounds like you are parsing some structure like JSON or XML? Have you checked whether the libraries you use for that have built-in methods for what you want?

Comment: Its working specifically with a dictionary, but yes possibly a library already has this but I haven't been able to find it for when a list is in the middle

Comment: Why do you use `yield` inside the loop?

Comment: Please provide relevant example(s).

Comment: @ScottHunter examples updated. Was planning to use yield to improve runtime

Comment: Why the `python-3.x` tag for code that's clearly Python 2?

Comment: `get` isn't defined for lists; why not just use `d = d[index]` and if that fails, return `False`?

Comment: Improving the runtime of something that doesn't work isn't the best plan.